# Core Data - Select by relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, swift

I have a one to many relationship between the `Father` and `Son` entities, where a `Father` may have no or N `Son`. Using `Core Data`, how do I get all `Son`, basing my search for a `Father`.

For example: I have a `Father` who owns the `Id` 1. I need to fetch all the `Son` has the `Father` with `Id` 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example working with NSManagedObject (subclassing is easier).

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Father" inManagedObjectContext:your_managedObjectContext]];
// You speak about you use Id, but is word reserved better use resourceId or something like that
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"resourceId=1"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *result = [your_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
NSManagedObject *father_Id1 = [result firstObject];
NSSet *sons = [father_Id1 valueForKey:@"theNameOfYourRelationshipSons"];
```

Comment: It´s the same but in both directions. Imagine in this cases instead of Father is PartOfParent, (Mather and Father). In this case is many to many, The code is the same. And you can make other request with entity Son, (it´s predicate, son with resourceId = 5), and ask for its Parents.

Comment: When the relationship is to one, and you call [theNSManagedObject valueForKey:@"theRelationShipToOne"] you have and object (and NSManagedObject). If it´s to many and you call [theNSManagedObject valueForKey:@"theRelationShipToMany"] you´d have many object (and NSSet with NSManagedObject)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a swift code that fetches all the Sons that has a father with id = 5

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Son")
fetchRequest = NSPredicate(format: "father.id == %@", argumentArray: [id])
let fathers = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [Father]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! And if it was the case of a many to many relationship?

Comment: If there were `fathers` relation in `Son` entity (which is never happen in real life :) ) The predicate format would be `fathers.id == %@`

Comment: Thank you! yes it is only a guess hehe